# What about the eigenvalues of $-\Delta_{p, q}$ in $W_0^{p}(\Omega)\times W_0^{1, q}(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $p, q \geq 1$. If $(\lambda_j)_j$ denotes the sequence of the eigenvalues of the $-\Delta_p$ in $W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$, what we can say about the sequence of the eigenvalues of $-\Delta_{(p, q)}$ in the product space $W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)\times W_0^{1, q}(\Omega)$?

Could anyone please help or give some references?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is $-\Delta_{p,q)} = (-\Delta _p, -\Delta_q)$?

Comment: @ArcticChar, yes, it is.